# NullPointer Exception while trying to access or read ReadOnly ctx in processElement method in KeyedBroadCastProcessFunction in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

I have some interesting scenario i am working on pattern matching in flink evaluating the incoming patterns using keyedbroadcastprocessfunction, when i am running the program in IDE i am getting null pointer exception in processElements function when trying to access ReadOnlyContext but it is running fine in terminal, below is my keyedbroadcastprocessfunction

Below is my Main Class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.restartstrategy.RestartStrategies;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.BasicTypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.MapTypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.flink.util.OutputTag;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SignalPatternMatchingApp {

    public static final MapStateDescriptor<String, Map<String, String>> patternRuleDescriptor =
            new MapStateDescriptor(SignalPatternMatchingConstants.PATTERN_RULE_DESCRIPTOR_NAME,
                    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, new MapTypeInfo<>(String.class, String.class));

 
    public static final OutputTag<JSONObject> unMatchedSideOutput =
            new OutputTag<JSONObject>("sideoutput") {
            };

 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        
        DataStream<JSONObject> inputSignal = get input from kafka stream

        DataStream<Map<String, String>> rawPatternStream =
                env.fromElements(get data from database);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>>> patternStream =
                rawPatternStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Map<String, String>,
                        Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(Map<String, String> patternRules,
                                        Collector<Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>>> out) throws Exception {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> stringEntry : patternRules.entrySet()) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringEntry.getValue());
                            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
                                String value = jsonObject.get(key).toString();
                                map.put(key, value);
                            }
                            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(stringEntry.getKey(), map));
                        }
                    }
                });

        BroadcastStream<Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>>> patternBroadcast =
                patternStream.broadcast(patternRuleDescriptor);


        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> matchedSignal =
                inputSignal.map(new MapFunction<JSONObject, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, JSONObject> map(JSONObject inputSignal) throws Exception {
                String sourceName = inputSignal.getJSONObject("signalHeader").get("sourceName").toString();
                return new Tuple2<>(sourceName, inputSignal);
            }
        }).keyBy(0).connect(patternBroadcast).process(new TestProcess());


        matchedSignal.print();
        
        DataStream<JSONObject> unmatchedSignal =
                ((SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>>) matchedSignal)
                .getSideOutput(unMatchedSideOutput);

        unmatchedSignal.print();

        env.execute();

    }
    

KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction as below




 public class TestProcess extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<String, sampleSignal>,
            Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>>, Tuple2<String, sampleSignal>> {

   MapStateDescriptor<String, Map<String, String>> patternRuleDesc;

    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        patternRuleDesc = new MapStateDescriptor<>("RuleDescriptor",
                BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,new MapTypeInfo<>(String.class,String.class));
    }
    
        public static final MapStateDescriptor <String,Map<String,String>> ruleDescriptor =
                new MapStateDescriptor <>("RuleDiscriptor",
                        ,BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
                        ,new MapTypeInfo<>(String.class,String.class));
    
        @Override
        public void processElement(Tuple2<String, sampleSignal> value, ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<Tuple2<String,
                sampleSignal>> out) throws Exception {
  
            Map<String,String> patternConditions  = ctx.getBroadcastState(this.patternRuleDesc).get(Key);
    
            System.out.println("Before Rule Iterator");
            
            /*I tried below way to print the values in broadcaststream just to print the values
              in broadcast state it don't print anything*/
              
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> rules:
                    patternConditions.entrySet()){
                System.out.println("Key: " +rules.getKey());
                System.out.println("Value: "+rules.getValue());
            }
    
            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(value.f0,value.f1));
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void processBroadcastElement(Tuple2<String, Map<String, String>> value, Context ctx,
                                            Collector<Tuple2<String, sampleSignal>> out) throws Exception {
    
            System.out.println("BroadCastState Key: " +value.f0);
            System.out.println("BroadCastState Value: " +value.f1);
            ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleDescriptor).put(value.f0,value.f1);
    
        }
    }
```

Below is the IDE Terminal output with error exception

```
 2020-07-07 12:15:19,349 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Flat Map (1/8) (1a117aa5347465fcc2cd5e58c286ccca) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,348 INFO  [TestProcess ] - BroadCastState SourceName: A
2020-07-07 12:15:19,350 INFO  [TestProcess ] - BroadCastState PatternCondition: PatternRule
2020-07-07 12:15:19,341 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Source: Collection Source (1/1) 23f6a4d19c5744a62c46ac48d4dfbb24.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (8/8) (773fad58ff1418ae919a0900e4da6ef5) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (8/8) (773fad58ff1418ae919a0900e4da6ef5).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/8) (67a21177a7598f3f1ccc5001fe6951c3) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/8) (67a21177a7598f3f1ccc5001fe6951c3).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [TestProcess ] - BroadCastState SourceName: A
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/8) (67a21177a7598f3f1ccc5001fe6951c3) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [TestProcess ] - BroadCastState PatternCondition: PatternRule
2020-07-07 12:15:19,351 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (8/8) (773fad58ff1418ae919a0900e4da6ef5) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (3/8) (8d860a734d5b6a50194a5caad135a844) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (3/8) (8d860a734d5b6a50194a5caad135a844).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (3/8) (8d860a734d5b6a50194a5caad135a844) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (1/8) (8fa9c71df79d439827a1d290d9ad9abd) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (1/8) (8fa9c71df79d439827a1d290d9ad9abd).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (1/8) (8fa9c71df79d439827a1d290d9ad9abd) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,357 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (4/8) (ee3c4e895e82f77ad9a055ee788f4a2b) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,357 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (4/8) (ee3c4e895e82f77ad9a055ee788f4a2b).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,357 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (4/8) (ee3c4e895e82f77ad9a055ee788f4a2b) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,358 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (6/8) (6a75da55421a929d4b3d4ebd655414e9) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,358 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (6/8) (6a75da55421a929d4b3d4ebd655414e9).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,339 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (3/8) (63a7c3f2b7a8d110232374c700e6378a) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (7/8) (351cc238fecce28d1dfdc5ac357ef8e4) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,352 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Map (3/8) d94aea75380e0e32c4747eef2f51a88d.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,358 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (7/8) (351cc238fecce28d1dfdc5ac357ef8e4).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,359 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (7/8) (351cc238fecce28d1dfdc5ac357ef8e4) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,360 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Flat Map (2/8) 32f2429b06954884543a4de062edf6f6.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,358 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (6/8) (6a75da55421a929d4b3d4ebd655414e9) [FINISHED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,360 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Map (1/8) 7dd6a325fe2265187b0b30bf3b4b8f63.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,358 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (4/8) (de310509f095e00584ce128336e19adf) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,361 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Map (5/8) 4920b55f28ea09128aaa4e0d9d4691d8.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,362 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Flat Map (8/8) 0fded4a7816a9d9a219c520891d2b38d.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,362 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Flat Map (1/8) 1a117aa5347465fcc2cd5e58c286ccca.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,363 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Map (7/8) (ac26eefbff14e55f031a055c1d6fa7f3) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,364 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/8) 67a21177a7598f3f1ccc5001fe6951c3.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,367 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (8/8) 773fad58ff1418ae919a0900e4da6ef5.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,367 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (5/8) (3bb74ec008b43ffe86edd6a7f84844a0) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,368 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (3/8) 8d860a734d5b6a50194a5caad135a844.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,368 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Map (2/8) (90787449e2373696163da5670b0e543a) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,369 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (1/8) 8fa9c71df79d439827a1d290d9ad9abd.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,370 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (4/8) ee3c4e895e82f77ad9a055ee788f4a2b.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,373 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (7/8) 351cc238fecce28d1dfdc5ac357ef8e4.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,374 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (6/8) 6a75da55421a929d4b3d4ebd655414e9.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,369 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (7/8) (c1ca47240e15ef6c60f1943aed1b45ba) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,379 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (23f6a4d19c5744a62c46ac48d4dfbb24) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,381 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Map (3/8) (d94aea75380e0e32c4747eef2f51a88d) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,382 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (2/8) (32f2429b06954884543a4de062edf6f6) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,384 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Map (1/8) (7dd6a325fe2265187b0b30bf3b4b8f63) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,385 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Map (5/8) (4920b55f28ea09128aaa4e0d9d4691d8) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,386 INFO  [TypeExtractor] - class org.json.JSONObject does not contain a getter for field map
2020-07-07 12:15:19,386 INFO  [TypeExtractor] - class org.json.JSONObject does not contain a setter for field map
2020-07-07 12:15:19,386 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (8/8) (0fded4a7816a9d9a219c520891d2b38d) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,386 INFO  [TypeExtractor] - Class class org.json.JSONObject cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,388 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Flat Map (1/8) (1a117aa5347465fcc2cd5e58c286ccca) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,390 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/8) (67a21177a7598f3f1ccc5001fe6951c3) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,390 INFO  [Task] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (5/8) (33a27b2d97c96658fd43db24177236bc) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.eventdetection.eventfilter.pattern.operator.json.filter.TestProcess .processElement(TestProcess .java:103)
    at com.eventdetection.eventfilter.pattern.operator.json.filter.TestProcess .processElement(TestProcess .java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.processElement1(CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processRecord1(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.lambda$new$0(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:311)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-07-07 12:15:19,394 INFO  [Task] - Freeing task resources for Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (5/8) (33a27b2d97c96658fd43db24177236bc).
2020-07-07 12:15:19,394 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (8/8) (773fad58ff1418ae919a0900e4da6ef5) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,394 INFO  [Task] - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (5/8) (33a27b2d97c96658fd43db24177236bc) [FAILED]
2020-07-07 12:15:19,395 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (3/8) (8d860a734d5b6a50194a5caad135a844) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,396 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (1/8) (8fa9c71df79d439827a1d290d9ad9abd) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,397 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (4/8) (ee3c4e895e82f77ad9a055ee788f4a2b) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,398 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (7/8) (351cc238fecce28d1dfdc5ac357ef8e4) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,399 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (6/8) (6a75da55421a929d4b3d4ebd655414e9) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,402 INFO  [TaskExecutor] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FAILED to JobManager for task Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (5/8) 33a27b2d97c96658fd43db24177236bc.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,404 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (5/8) (33a27b2d97c96658fd43db24177236bc) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.eventdetection.eventfilter.pattern.operator.json.filter.PatternFilter.processElement(PatternFilter.java:103)
    at com.eventdetection.eventfilter.pattern.operator.json.filter.PatternFilter.processElement(PatternFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.processElement1(CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processRecord1(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.lambda$new$0(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:311)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-07-07 12:15:19,406 INFO  [RestartPipelinedRegionStrategy] - Calculating tasks to restart to recover the failed task d8804397962a5c1c0b4daacb1802fb97_4.
2020-07-07 12:15:19,408 INFO  [RestartPipelinedRegionStrategy] - 26 tasks should be restarted to recover the failed task d8804397962a5c1c0b4daacb1802fb97_4. 
2020-07-07 12:15:19,410 INFO  [ExecutionGraph] - Job Pattern-Matching (1a828d53bc6a886fe0fc7c454e6e66b7) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:484)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:279)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:194)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Please help in solving the issue i am using FLINK 1.10.0 version and INTELLiJ IDE and Java Version 1.8

Comment: There is also a null point on the `StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput`. I guess you are trying to process some event that is null. But the other null pointer at `incomingRule.size()` it is really strange.

Comment: @Felipe thanks for the reply i missed one more error i am getting following error but i am using the same mapstate descriptor and i am using it in broadcasting the stream too Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The requested state does not exist. Check for typos in your state descriptor, or specify the state descriptor in the datastream.broadcast(...) call if you forgot to register it.

Comment: I guess the problem could be how you instantiate your `MapStateDescriptor`. You have to instantiate it inside the open method, which you have to overload from a `RichFunction`. Here is one example: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state

Comment: Yeah, I really don't think the error arises where You think it does. What exacly is `incomingPattern` and `Key` ?

Comment: @Felipe ya even tried that approach too declaring open method and initiating the Mapstate but still i am seeing same null pointer exception

Comment: @DominikWosiński incomingPattern is the rule for particular source which is nothing but key...i am trying to read only the rules of particular source based on key instead of iterating through broadcast state and applying all the rules on the stream i am creating a map of rules based on sourcename and iterating through only those values

Comment: @Felipe any suggestion here what i am doing wrong

Comment: I don't know exactly. Your example is very confusing and the error does not match with your code. Thus, it is hard to help (at least for me). I suggest that you start with a `Hello World` working example like this (https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/26/broadcast-state.html) and improve step-by-step to see where it brokes.

Comment: @David Anderson can you please comment on this

Comment: I agree with Felipe here, there are multiple inconsistencies in the code You are presenting. For example, what is `patternRuleDesc`? It wasn't declared anywhere in the class but it is assigned in the `open` method.

Comment: @DominikWosiński patternRuleDesc is map state descriptor sorry i missed it to mention in the code

Answer (score 1):

The only place it can actually fail, assuming the current state of the code is this part:

```
 Map<String,String> patternConditions  = ctx.getBroadcastState(this.patternRuleDesc).get(Key);
    
            System.out.println("Before Rule Iterator");
            
            /*I tried below way to print the values in broadcaststream just to print the values
              in broadcast state it don't print anything*/
              
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> rules:
                    patternConditions.entrySet()){
                System.out.println("Key: " +rules.getKey());
                System.out.println("Value: "+rules.getValue());
            }
```

The problem is not really getting the broadcast state as it should never throw `NullPointerException`, but rather `IllegalArgumentException`. The problem is that You get some `Key` and then try to perform some operation on this (`.entryset()`). But if the given `Key` is not present the state will work just as a normal `Map` meaning it will return `null`. And if You will try to perform operation on `null` You will get `NullPointerException`.

You should add some code to verify that the given `Key` is in the state otherwise it can always fail.

EDIT:

So, if the question is about the race between BroadcastStream and another stream, that is not something You can prevent easily. That is because the pace at which consumers consume messages can differ and it's impossible to normally prevent this.
There are two ways I can see You can try to tackle this:

1. Create `ListState` that will keep elements that arrived and didn't have a corresponding `Key`, then You would simply emit them whenever given `Key` arrives. Note: You have to emit them from `processElement` since `BroadcastState` is not keyed.
2. Use `InputSelectable` to write an operator that prefers one source over another, this way You could prefer Broadcast Stream over the stream of elements.

Generally, I would say that Option 1 is simpler and faster to introduce if You have continuous stream of data i.e. You know that given `Key` will arrive more than once. Option 2 gives more flexibility, but also requires more knowledge and is generally harder to implement correctly.

Comment: i agree with the key is present and because of that its throwing NPE what i observed is broadcast stream and datastream are racing against each other and this exception is not consistent some times it won't throw NPE and runs fine but some times it throws NPE what i observed when running the program in debug mode for successful run first broadcast method in KeyedBroadCastProcessFn is executing first for failure case first processElement method is executing because of that the map state is empty i am looking for hint how can i make sure first broadcast state excuted first

Comment: Ah, so I think You perhaps should make it clearer in the question, because at least for me it's not clear that this is what You are asking about :) Edited answer

Comment: you said Edited answer sorry i am not figure out what is updated in answer can you please point out that and i agree with you the question is not clear initially when i was facing this issue i though i am doing something wrong but after debugging a lot i understood that the processElement method is executing before broadcast method because of that the map state is empty and throwing NPE i would have updated the question sorry for that

Comment: Yes, sorry I had some issue and the answer was not added correctly :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately i can't use list state in my case key is nothing but the source from which the data is coming from and i am getting it as part of signal and i am using flatmap function in order to extract key so i am not facing NPE with empty key and InputSelectable is not suitable in my case and i figured out what is issue the incoming signal i am receiving is avro signal and i am reading patterns from JSON file and because of this avro signal is getting processed first compared to the stream with jsonobject so i changed avro to jsonobject